# Pushstate doesn't fire when pushed URL is the same as current

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate, history.js, browser-state

I've built a primitive routing function for a site I'm working on.
The idea is to check the incoming URL and then send the browser to the appropriate part of the site.

I've noticed that pushState doesn't fire if the incoming URL is the same as the one that it's supposed to push to. Meaning, if I go to `domain.com/journal` it won't fire. The URL is the same as the one the router is supposed to push to: `History.pushState({ id: 'journal' }, site.title+' — '+'Journal', site.url+'/journal' );`). 
But if I put `domain.com/journal/` instead, it will fire. Why is that?

**Simplified routing code**

```
setTimeout(function() {
      uri = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
      if(uri === 'journal') {
        uri = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        if(uri[2]) {
          History.pushState({ id: 'post', no: uri[2] }, site.title+' — '+'Journal', site.url+'/journal/'+uri[2] );
        } else {
          History.pushState({ id: 'journal' }, site.title+' — '+'Journal', site.url+'/journal' );
        }
      } else if(uri === 'contact') {
        History.pushState({ id: 'contact' }, site.title+' — '+'Contact', site.url+'/contact' );
      } else {
        History.pushState({ id: 'gallery' }, site.title, site.url );
      }
}, 1);

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state  
    Roots.common.history(State);
}

history: function(State) {
    navigate(State.data.id, State.data.no);
},

navigate: function(section, no) {
  if(section === 'gallery') {
    // do gallery stuff
  } else if(section === 'journal') {
    // do journal stuff
  } else if(section === 'contact') {
    // do contact stuff
  } else if(section === 'post') {
    // do post stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to make it fire no matter what is to send random data together with the pushState

```
History.pushState({ id: 'gallery', randomData: window.Math.random() }, site.title, site.url );
```